# Best practicies to organize Authentication with Axis2

Tags: web-services, authentication, authorization, apache-axis

We need to build a number of web servics with axis2. And for each of them we need an authorization and authentication mechanisms.

Is there some common methods or specifications how to implement this functionality quickly and easily?

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used it myself so I don't know if this is what you are looking for, but have a look at [Rampart](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Rampart_module). It is a [module](http://ws.apache.org/axis2/modules/rampart/1_0/security-module.html) which implements the WS-Security standard for the Axis2 Web services.